# vector implementation of Gradient Descent with multiple theta

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I am trying to implement gradient descent in octave for function having multiple theta value . Do you have any sample so?

Comment: Well.. This is stackoverflow, not a search engine. Try google.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradient Descent implementation in octave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591343/gradient-descent-implementation-in-octave)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was already answered in other question 4 years ago:
[Gradient Descent implementation in octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591343/gradient-descent-implementation-in-octave)

Use the code from there and probably update it a bit to match your specifics.